# Returning JSONArray or JSONObject from ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

I have the following method...

I am trying to verify results in a oracle DB. The result is not what I expect, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it right without doing a map, or list/map.

```
public static JSONArray verifyDRFromButton(String transactionId) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet;
        Constants.threadSleep(5000);
        Constants.verifyOracle();
        String databaseConnectionString = String.format("jdbc:oracle:thin:@%s:%s:%s",  "*****", "****", "*****");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseConnectionString,"*****","*****");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from ****** WHERE ***** = '" + transactionId + "'");
        //Print DB Table
        Constants.threadSleep(500);
        //DBTablePrinter.printResultSet(rs);
        //result = rs.toString();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int totalRows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();    
                obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                        .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
                jsonArray.put(obj);
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

The result looks like this...

```
[
    {"id": "idvalue"}, 
    {"id2": "id2value"}, 
    {"name": "namevalue"}, 
    {"name2": "name2value"}
]
```

I would like it to be.

```
[
    {"id": "idvalue", "id2": "id2value"}, 
    {"name": "namevalue", "name2": "name2value"}
]
```

Comment: Please do not name totalRows = columnCount. You go through 4 columns and insert each of them into the json array. If you want to split them, you will have to collate the pairs of columns together.

Comment: the DB has about 28 columns. and at a time, there could be 2-6 rows. the renaming is just a name... i can move the new JSONObject() before the for loop, but it creates 56 (two rows, 28columns)

Comment: if you only need 4 columns from the db then why not make your query more specific? instead of selecting all (`*`)?  Would be much easier to build your json string then

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte i cant justify making everything static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject()
```

Before the for loop and this line

```
jsonArray.put(obj);
```

After for the loop
If you do not get intended results please share your results

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use JSON-P (https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/index.html) which is the standard JSON specification in enterirpise Java, since Java EE 7.

Second, this

```
[
    {"id":, "idvalue"}, 
    {"id2":, "id2value"}, 
    {"name":, "namevalue"}, 
    {"name2":, "name2value"}
]
```

is not a valid JsonArray, since the contained objects are not valid JSONs.
So there must be something wrong with your algorithm.

Third, if you use JSON-P, which is based on interfaces, you can add your implementation of JsonArray, based on the ResultSet: this means you can at least hide that procedural mess if not even refactor it and make it more elegant.

The idea is to make the ResultSet *act* as a JsonArray, not to transform it into a JsonArray. More about this topic, here: https://www.amihaiemil.com/2017/10/16/javaee8-jsoncollectors-oop-alternative.html

Comment: ill look into it. and thats a type on my half. i added a , my mistake. i fixed in my question